# Running bash builtin command "type" from script does not work for aliases

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to check if a command exists from a Bash script. I use the Bash builtin command `type -t` and it works well except for aliases.
Here is an example:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "> Defining alias lll.."
alias lll='ls'
echo "> Testing type of lll.." 
type -t lll
echo "> Return code form type -t: $?"
echo "> Checking that alias lll is really defined.."
alias lll
echo "> Testing type -t for ordinary command 'ls' ( not alias )"
type -t ls
```

The output is:

```
> Defining alias lll..
> Testing type of lll..
> Return code form type -t: 1
> Checking that alias lll is really defined..
alias lll='ls'
> Testing type -t for ordinary command 'ls' ( not alias )
file
```

Why does `type -t lll` give return code 1 ( not found )? When I run this command from the terminal window, it works well (gives return code 0) so it seems the problem is specific to the script setting..

Comment: I am not sure why this question was marked as a duplicate

Comment: *You need to do `shopt -s expand_aliases` in the script*

Comment: @Cyrus Yes it works with `expand_aliases`! I did not realialize that even if `alias lll` showed that `lll` was defined as an alias, it was not "expanded" into a recognizable command by Bash. Aliases are a little bit confusing I think.

Comment: Confusing sometimes, and can be a support nightmare when mis-used.  Consider functions instead.  You might find them less confusing.